# How do I stop opening files in new visual studio solutions?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, solution

My work requires that I retrieve javascript files from a TFS repository in Visual Studio 2012, correct any errors or make necessary changes, then commit them back to TFS.

I recently had a colleague go on holiday, so I had to open a solution to run a C# program from the solution in his absence.

Since running this solution, I've now got all my javascript files opening in a new solution, which is annoying as I have to close the solution without saving it every time I want to do a commit.

How do I stop Visual Studio from opening the files in a new solution, and get it back to its previous behaviour of just opening the file?